# If two planes intersect in a line that lies in another plane, what is the solution set for the corresponding system of equations of the planes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, matrix-equations

If two planes intersect in a line that lies in another plane, what is the solution set for the corresponding system of equations of the planes?

Attempt: The solution set contains infinitely many elements and could be written as $\{(x, y, z) : (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \} $. But what method is suitable to prove such an assumption?

Comment: You need to specify what planes are you talking about, planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$? when three planes intersect in the same line then the solution set of the system of the $3$ equations of the $3$ planes is naturally the line of intersection.

Comment: The set you’ve written is all of $\Bbb R^3$. Start by answering the question in words. You’re not going to have an explicit set formulation unless you think of a way to give equations for the planes.

Comment: The equations are presumably those for the planes. I.e., a point is in the plane if and only if its coordinates satisfy the equation. The solution set of the system is the set of all points that satisfy the equations. I.e., the set of all points that are in all three planes. Now read the information given again. Can you figure out from that information what the set is that contains points that are in all three planes?